# Why my links in the website(just online) show like this: href=\"http://link\"?

Tags: cpanel

I use ckeditor in my website, when i add link or image in the textarea after submit the form All links and images change to this style:

For links : `href=\"link\"`
For images: `src=\"link\"`

Please help me

Comment: A stupidly ancient/badly configured/out-of-date PHP install with magic_quotes enabled?

Comment: The `magic_quotes_gpc` idiocy strikes again.

Comment: I think problem is from my CPANEL, anyone have same problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u guys for guide me, i used this code as solution:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        unset($process[$key][$k]);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
            $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
        } else {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }
}
unset($process);
}#insert this code in top of your main file body
```